# The element 'configuration' in namespace 'MyWindsorSchema' has invalid child element 'configSections' in namespace 'MyWindsorSchema'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, web-config

In order to create the following section,

```
<section name="castle"
           type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,
         Castle.Windsor" />
```

I downloaded and put the "**CastelWindsorSchema**" in my C drive (as it was suggested by the read-me file). I referenced it this way in the Web.Config: (I kept everything as it is because I create the dev and castle in the C drive)

```
    <configuration xmlns="MyWindsorSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="MyWindsorSchema file://c:\dev\castle\windsor.xsd">
```

I'm getting the following warning:

The element '*configuration*' in namespace '*MyWindsorSchema*' has invalid child element 'configSections' in namespace 'MyWindsorSchema'. List of possible elements expected: '*include, properties, facilities, components*' in namespace '**MyWindsorSchema**'.

The configSections tag, which comes right after the configuration tag, is highlighted in bleu.

Am I missing anyting??? Maybe I need to change "MyWindsorSchema" to something else???

Thanks for the help

Rich

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which schema you're talking about, but perhaps it is targeted towards standalone Windsor config file, not the web.config section?

Anyway, Windsor has pretty minimalistic and logical config structure so actually once you start working with it, you'll find you don't really need schema at all. [Take a look](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/manual/windsorconfigref.html).